# Create a log of users country from their IP

Tags: php, function, logging, geolocation, ip

I am using this function to get the two-letter country code:

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details->country;
```

**Output:**

```
US // Two-letter Country Code
```

And to make a log in a file, I was thinking of using something like this:

```
$file = 'visitors.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $ipaddress . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Output:**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xx // with a line break after
```

I want to loop through the country codes and display them with the number of visitors from each country. For example:

If two IP Addresses from US and 1 IP Address from Canada went on the page... I want to display:

```
US: 2
CA: 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use Database

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a database (no particular reason)

Comment: I agree with @Kermani. It would be more manageable and easier to implement.

Comment: @imbondbaby with database you can have some other column to save your user ip, timestamp, number of visits, unique visits, and ... . With this information you can design UX better and show each user the stuff what they want to see on your website because you know who they are and how do the think!

Comment: You could even use json or nosql?

Comment: @Darren What is nosql means?

Comment: @Kermani [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56992/discussion-between-kermani-and-darren).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't like the idea of working with text files here - here is an easy solution for that task (untested):

```
<?php
// Setup.
$pathVisitorsFile = 'visitors.txt';

// Execution.
if(!file_exists($pathVisitorsFile)) {
    die('File "'. $pathVisitorsFile .'" not found');
}

// Read entries.
$visitorsCountry = file($pathVisitorsFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Count entries.
$foundCountries = array();
foreach($visitorsCountry as $visitorCountry) {
    if(!isset($foundCountries[$visitorCountry])) {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry] = 1;
    } else {
        $foundCountries[$visitorCountry]++;
    }
}

// Display entries.
echo('<ul>');
foreach($foundCountries as $countryCode => $visitors) {
    echo('<li>'. $countryCode .': '. $visitors .'</li>');
}
echo('</ul>');
?>
```

I assumed that you already have a file with contents like:

```
US
US
US
DE
DE
IR
AT
US
```